# Highstock Monthly column stock - x-axis data labels are not proper

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, highcharts

I have following data for plotting highstock column monthly chart :

```
X_Axis          Y_Axis  

2017-09-30  1007978106.7941
2017-08-01  384903346.4478
2017-07-01  385113848.5507
2017-06-01  432772510.2959
2017-05-01  966556324.3829
2017-04-01  384683039.0594
2017-03-01  431784555.0991
2017-02-01  384093193.8944
2017-01-01  964423591.0024
2016-12-01  432168907.4964
2016-11-01  384955532.7725
2016-10-01  385357775.1043
2016-09-01  1012465246.9779
```

It won't plot the data in Sep 2017 instead of it is showing in Oct 2017. why?

Please find the attachment.
[image]

Comment: Please try to better format the data and ask for a more clear question. What is the exact problem? and what are you trying to achieve?